# How to solve -f : command not found

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check some files existence using -f command followed by the file bath but I have an error. This is my script:

```
initUCounter="/home/teeba/users_counter_initial_value"
initPCounter="/home/teeba/number_of_processes"
if [! -f $initUCounter && ! -f $initPCounter]
then
echo "0" > /tmp/users_counter_initial_value
echo "1" > /tmp/processes_counter_initial_value
fi
```

Comment: What is the command entered and what is the full output?

Comment: `-f` is not an existing command. words beginning with a `-` usually are option, as in `apt-get download -f` where "apt-get" is the package used, "download" is the command to tell what the package needs to do and "-f" is an option to force the download even if errors appear

Comment: @MrVaykadji oh no `-f` in bash scripting is used to check for the presence of a file.

Comment: @MrVaykadji: that `-f` **is** a flag to the command `test`, that has `[` as a kind of alias. (It is more complex really --- try man `test`.) The OP clearly meant to use the `[[ ... ]]` logical test operator of `bash`

Comment: you can check it by running `[ -f /etc/apt/sources.list ] && echo "File is present" || echo "No such file"` command.

Comment: Nice, I learned. Thanks, you'll get +10 rep ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from Rmano's answer you can use,

```bsh
if [ ! -f $initUCounter ] && [ ! -f $initPCounter ]; then
    some action
else
    some other action
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the bash `[[ ]]` operator and not the `[` command (`[` is the same as the command `test`):

```
if [[ ! -f $initUCounter && ! -f $initPCounter ]]
```

this should work.

See [this discussion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D) for more details. (The [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page is a must read when you start to write scripts... will save you from hours of head-scratching)

Comment: You should probably be using -r or -w rather than (or in addition to) -f, since you almost always want to do something with the file after checking it.  Knowing it's a file is great, but knowing it's a readable file before you try to read it is even better. ;)